# Modifying a file using C System Calls

Tags: c, system-calls

I want to modify a specific byte in a file using C system calls. I have some knowledge about open() and read() and  write() system calls.

Say i want to modify 1024th byte in a file and file has 2048 bytes. So i can read out 1024 bytes to a character array using read() and change the required byte.

Now when i write back that modified character array to the file does the rest of the file remain same? Learning materials are not clear on this one. Please help me understand this.

Comment: Try it and you will see.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I think lseek() function will help me do it. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: ...It seems like you know how to write it. Why not do that and _test_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this portably with the standard streams from `<stdio.h>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* uppercase letter at offset 1024 */
FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "r+b");
if (fp) {
    fseek(fp, 1024L, SEEK_SET);
    int c = getc(fp);
    if (c != EOF) {
        fseek(fp, 1024L, SEEK_SET);
        putc(toupper((unsigned char)c), fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

If you have access to the Posix API, you can use the system calls directly, but be aware that `write()` may return early in some cases.  It should not be a problem for just writing a single byte, but may become an issue if you write change large chunks of files. The stream interface is simpler to use.  Here is the Posix code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* uppercase letter at offset 1024 */
unsigned char uc;
int hd = open("filename", O_RDWR | O_BINARY);
if (hd >= 0) {
    lseek(hd, 1024L, SEEK_SET);
    if (read(hd, &uc, 1) == 1) {
        lseek(hd, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
        uc = toupper(uc);
        write(hd, &uc, 1);
    }
    close(hd);
}
```

Comment: i was wondering how to do this using system calls rather than c functions. But thanks your answer lead me to lseek() system call.